# rosjava_core tutorial error in source

Tags: rosjava, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I wanted to run rosjava_tutorial_pubsub and rosjava_tutorial_services in eclipse. These need the project rosjava. But there is an error in the source code. In the src/test/java, int the org.ros package in ParameterServerTestNode.java
At line number 112 it gives this error: **The method setInt32Array(List) in the type TestArrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[])**

Just to let you know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33184/rosjava_core-tutorial-error-in-source/) by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to rebuild everything since the message API changed recently. gradlew clean install

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0